# KL divergence loss goes to zero while training VAE

Tags: deep-learning, tf.keras, autoencoder, supervised-learning

I am trying to train a supervised variational autoencoder to perform  classification for a noisy dataset. I am using a fully connected encoder and decoder where uses the z as input for an MLP. I'm using the Adam optimizer with a learning rate of 1e-3. However my network Kl loss reach value of `4.4584e-04` after 5 epochs and the network does not learn anything after that. What could be the reason? Should I need to get stratified batches?

I used keras and tensorflow for implementation and used variaous embeding dimension for latent space of VAE.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this can happen when you have the beta (coeficient that multiplies the KL) too big, and the NN is giving too much importance to the KL loss. Just shrink it to make your NN focus in training the reconstruction loss instead.

Comment: Do you mean that a small beta, will help the NN to converge faster?

Comment: The thing is if the beta is too high, the kl loss will basically collapse.